# How to obtain the image ID?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images

I need a unique ID for each image in Magento store for a special use case.

So I'm trying to figure a way to reliably obtain the product image ID. Is that the `$image["value_id"]` field?

I tried this:

```
 foreach ($collection as $product) {
     $imageUrl = (string)Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image')->resize(480);
     $galleryData = $product->getMediaGalleryImages();
     foreach($galleryData as $image) {
         $imageId = $image['value_id'];
     }
 }
```

Sometimes it works, sometimes it returns null, even when $imageUrl has a valid URL for the image. Is that because an image with a single product photo doesn't have a media gallery?

I need a reliable way to get the image ID for every product that has an image.

Comment: Turns out I was having this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7890616/get-product-media-gallery-images-from-a-product-collection-in-magento & answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5900522/how-to-load-products-media-gallery-along-with-the-collection

Answer (score 1):

I tested on my local Magento 1.9 and I could get `$image['value_id']` if there is any image in the product even if it is single image.

I didn't get `$image['value_id']` when there is no image in the product, (placeholder image is displayed for the product).

If there is no image in the product, even then you get value for `$imageUrl` and that will be the image url of placeholder image.